# Understanding postgres db server power on Azure

Tags: virtual-machines, azure

I'm considering switching from AWS to Azure and I need to compare my amazon RDS with the Azure postgres DB server power.

I picked a postgres server with "800 ACU" and I read here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/acu that 100 ACU = Standard_A1, which has 1 vCPU and 1.75Gib memory.

Does that mean that a DB server on Azure with 800 ACU = 8 vCPU and 14Gib memory? Or is there something extra I'm missing somewhere? 14Gib doesn't sound that much for a db server.

Also, what exactly is a single vCPU on Azure?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does that mean that a DB server on Azure with 800 ACU = 8 vCPU and
>   14Gib memory?

You are right, per vCPU with 100 ACU in standard size.

For example, if you want to create a VM with 800 ACU, we can select VM size to `Standard_A4` or `Standard_A7`:

Here is the screenshot about ACU:
[image]

Here is the size of Azure VM:

[image]

In your scenario, I think we can choose `Standard_A4` and `Standard_A7`, if you need more `Memory`, I think we can choose `Standard_A7`.

Comment: thank you, I don't think there's a machine type choice though when creating postgres server, all I get there is two sliders of disk size and ACU. that's why I was asking the question - 14Gib seems very little for a large db yet it doesn't seem to be possible to change it.  Do you know a way that I missed somewhere?

Comment: via Azure portal. New -> Azure Database for PostgreSQL. its a preview feature.

Comment: @RonenNess Sorry for my misunderstand. The memory is pre-configured and optimized per compute unit based on the service tier you choose. Standard tier has 2x the memory per compute unit compared to Basic tier. We recommend for predictable performance you choose standard tier. You can monitor the memory utilization using the memory_percent metrics. hope that helps:)

Comment: Yeah that's what I picked, waiting for the Premium tier to open up :)  Thanks!

Comment: @RonenNess Here is the Azure database postgresql team's post, please check [it](https://www.reddit.com/r/AZURE/comments/6ii7kb/ama_azure_database_for_postgresql_team_622/). but I can't find the memory size per ACU:(